# Regex get string between string and newline

Tags: regex

i have this string pattern:

```
Name: bondy
address: kuta, bali
age: 20
```

i want to get the name value of `Name` i did regex like this:

```
/(?<=Name:)(.*)(?=[\n\r])
```

but somehow it reads until the last newline?

demo: https://regex101.com/r/4U6iU1/1

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier using the multiline flag or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: to be honest, i'm not into regex, still start learning on it therefore i dont understand your question. can you please elaborate in sample codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(.*)` is greedy and will try to match everything.  Add a `?` right after the asterisk to have it be less greedy.

`(.*?)` tested and worked.